# Misalignment of titles, sections as well as the contents title in document class {refart}

Tags: align, document-classes, lyx-layouts

I currently wonder on the best way to align the title, sections and table of contents title in `documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{refart}`. To illustrate my point, please find below:

As a way around I had to use `\phantom{text}` to align the title, although I acknowledge that this approach is sub-optimal. Furthermore it cannot be used to align the sections, unfortunately.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{refart}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\SetWatermarkText{Confidential}
\SetWatermarkScale{5}
\SetWatermarkColor[rgb]{0.7,0,0}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} %for subscript
\usepackage{amsmath} % for use \text{} in a math mode

\usepackage[headheight=20mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width = 0.25\textwidth, 
 height=15.0mm]{pic}}
 \fancyhead[L]{}

\title{\textbf{\phantom{dddddddddddd}AAAAAAA}}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
\begin{abstract}
test
\end{abstract}


\tableofcontents
\section{ TESTING VERY LONG SECTION TITLE 1}

\subsection{IDEM TESTING SUB-SECTION}

\end{document}
\bibliography
\newpage
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance

**output:**

```
       ---------------------------------------------------------
  AAAA  % title without using \phantom(text) to align the title

       ---------------------------------------------------------
 s  % instead of contents

       ----------------------------------------------------------

 TESTING VERY LONG SECTION TITLE 1 % section
       --------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Very strange class this `refart`. Use `showframe` option within `geometry` to see what happens.

Comment: `\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}` is not matching my expectations since it frames the whole document as opposed to inserting only two horizontal lines in which the title is inserted. Furthermore the option clashes with other packages.

Comment: `\usepackage[headheight=20mm,showframe]{geometry}` is only to show you how bad the format is. The text is completely out of margins. I have no idea why, but that class is quite strange.

Comment: Off-topic: `fixltx2e` is not necessary any longer since 2015 ... and `hyperref` is loaded too early and twice...... and `refart` seems to have aged... and two \end{document}s...

Comment: `\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}` ????

Comment: The issue is `geometry` here!

Comment: `\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}` to remove the `Abstract title`

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: you're right since commenting `%\usepackage[headheight=20mm]{geometry}` solves the problem. However this creates an additional issue to the extent that a picture could no longer be used as `header`

Comment: @dark.vador: I don't recommend this class however. It's outdated, in my point of view, only meant for typesetting reference manuals (according to its German documentation). The last update seems to be from 2006 (or even older)

Comment: @dark.vador: If nothing else helps, omitting `geometry` `\headheight=20mm` seems to cure the problem. But I don't recommend this explicit layout changing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class is incompatible with `geometry` as it uses a nonstandard page layout.

Since you just need to change the head height, use a lower level method, that is,

```
\setlength{\headheight}{48pt}
```

For the example I disabled the watermarks, that are irrelevant to show what's happening. By the way, the head height should be at least 47pt, as told by `fancyhdr`. You'll probably have to reduce the text height a bit.

About centering the title: this is not how the class does it.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{refart}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
%\usepackage{draftwatermark}
\usepackage[euler]{textgreek}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for use \text{} in a math mode

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{hyperref}

%\SetWatermarkText{Confidential}
%\SetWatermarkScale{5}
%\SetWatermarkColor[rgb]{0.7,0,0}
%\SetWatermarkText{Confidential}
%\SetWatermarkScale{5}
%\SetWatermarkColor[rgb]{0.7,0,0}

 \pagestyle{fancy}
 \fancyhead{}% clear the headers
 \fancyhead[R]{\includegraphics[width = 0.25\textwidth, height=15.0mm]{example-image}}

\setlength{\headheight}{48pt}% how fancyhdr thinks it should be

\title{AAAAAAA}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\renewcommand{\abstractname}{\vspace{-\baselineskip}}
\begin{abstract}
test
\end{abstract}


\tableofcontents

\section{ TESTING VERY LONG SECTION TITLE 1}

\lipsum[2]

\subsection{IDEM TESTING SUB-SECTION}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

[image]

If you really need to center the title:

```
\newcommand{\centertitle}{%
  \centering
  \setlength{\leftskip}{\glueexpr-\leftmarginwidth+\leftskip}%
}

\title{\centertitle AAAAAAA}
```

[image]

Some more notes.

1. `hyperref` should be loaded last
2. `fixltx2e` is not needed any longer
3. `lipsum` is only loaded for providing mock text
4. You probably want to load `fix-cm` with

   ```
   \RequirePackage{fix-cm}
   ```

   before `\documentclass`.